# Toshiba portege R830 fan always running even on idle

Tags: windows-7, fan, system-recovery, sysprep, acronis-trueimage

I'm trying to install a software which I had from image backup which I was using for the past few years without a problem even on dissimilar hardware (loading appropriate driver...)

Until I recovered the image on this laptop then two issues happened.

The first issue is when windows boot up and show the logon screen the fan speed goes to 100% and doesn't go down and the processor is idle

When I use a fresh windows  installation the problem doesn't happen so Its not a hardware problem.

so I want to know what is responsible of the fan speed ? Is it some driver ?
I even backed up my drivers from from the fresh windows installation and restored them to the recovered installation and the problem still exist

What's more weird is after logon and the fan going crazy to 100% when i hibernate the laptop and then start it again the fan start working fine (only increasing is the CPU is on load)

The second problem is the acronis image which I recover to my other laptops recovers fine but on this toshiba its recovered but nothing work even the desktop doesn't show up when enter to taskmgr and add explorer.exe the desktop shows up but that's it i can't open any folders all programs don't have icons and are giving german error message

On all other laptops using the same image it recovers just fine
I can't understand why this happens only on this laptop

Answer (score 1):

> so I want to know what is responsible of the fan speed ? Is it some
> driver ?

Yes. Out of date Power Management drivers will cause this and such drivers were likely updated in the fresh install.

New PM drivers also may require new BIOS and other drivers.

> Until I recovered the image on this laptop then two issues happened.
>
> The first issue is when windows boot up and show the logon screen the
> fan speed goes to 100% and doesn't go down and the processor is idle
>
> When I use a fresh windows installation the problem doesn't happen so
> Its not a hardware problem

This would point to an incompatible image for the machine. You were using the image on Lenovo and then put it on a Toshiba.  (Question should be edited for clarity). This is verified by the use of a fresh install

Comment: Its not a virus issue since these images are done on clean install then baked up and used them every time and with antivirus installed and the antivirus has never complained about any virus.also not only one image that have this issue in fact none of the images i have worked while they worked on lenovo dell hp latops and never had any issues

Comment: I was referring to the issue on the old install (You said "until I recovered the image" , so I take that to be a prior install.

Comment: There was some lack of clarity but I took the virus sentences out, because it is more clearly now an image issue.

Comment: If its an image issue it wouldn't work on any other laptop the problem is it works fine on any other laptop expect this one.also I did a sysprep that solved the files not loaded properly the image work fine except for the fan issue.I couldn't find the driver online for power management can you show it to me if you could find it

Comment: There is this site (model not exact) :  https://www.toshiba-windows-drivers.com/2012/07/toshiba-satellite-r830-windows-7-64bit.html   and this site (not Toshiba) :   https://www.notebook-driver.com/toshiba-portege-r830-windows-driver-utility/  .  These might help.

Answer (score 0):

@Jwdsoft i have also seen the issue you are talking about. I am not sure what CPU you have, but some newer CPU's have software that controls them. As @John said, there could be Drivers that are causing the issue, viruses or corrupt software.

There could be a Hardware issue on the CPU as well that somehow correlates to the software you were installing.

I don't anything about acronis image, so i can't help you there.

Comment: The CPU is intel core I3-2310M.I backed up all the drivers from the clean windows 7 installation and restored all of them to the new restored installation but still the same problem so even the drivers has been replaced.what's puzzling me is when I hibernate the laptop and turn it on again the fan doesn't go to 100% it works perfectly so something is causing to go 100% at logon only

Comment: Ahh. So i looked at the CPU schematics and everything seems fine. I am not familiar with windows 7, but there may be an error may be in the BIOS settings, or when windows 7 is turned on it just locks on 100%. But whenever i turn on my laptop, it goes to the max for like 2 secs and then goes down to its normal position. I will try and look more into it.

Comment: I have heard from a distant friend of mine that Toshiba's laptops suffered from a programming error that hindered its lifespan. I am not sure what models, or if this is accurate, but maybe that is playing a role?